# How to access another docker image ENV when buildind a second docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say I set ENV VAR=foo while building image1.

Can I access this VAR from another Dockerfile, like the COPY --from synthax?

I need to do this without building "FROM image1"

Comment: Short answer is that you can't. The long answer is that you probably can, but it'll be extremely messy. I tried and I couldn't get it to work. And I'm pretty good at writing messy code :)

Comment: In general, one process can't access another's environment, Docker or otherwise.